# Is it possible to copy a file in a docker-compose.yml file?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I understand that you can mount a volume, but is it possible to copy a file in the docker-compose.yml file?

Comment: Hi Adeyemo Qudus, welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you please be a little more specific? What have tried already? Maybe an example? Edit your question, and we'll be able to help you better.

Comment: How is this distinct from using the `COPY` command in a Dockerfile?

Comment: I had similar problem and I just used volumes to mount a directory and I copied that directory within the container. There I could manipulate files without affecting external directory.